# Different outputs running same code locally and on leetcode

Tags: linked-list

Running this piece of code locally or in repl.it outputs the right result but when running it in leetcode as a submission throws an error

```py
def create_linked_lst(lst):
    linked_lst = ListNode()
    tmp = linked_lst
    if len(lst) == 0:
        tmp.val = ''
        return linked_lst
        
    for item in lst:
        if lst.index(item) < len(lst)-1:
            tmp.val = item 
            #print ("__> ",tmp.val)
            tmp.next = ListNode()
            tmp = tmp.next
    tmp.val = lst[-1]
    #print ("__> ",tmp.val)

    return linked_lst


class Solution:
    def mergeTwoLists(self , l1, l2):


      lst1 = [] 
      lst2 = [] 

      def linked_lst_to_lst(lst):
        tmp = []
        while lst.next != None:
          tmp.append(lst.val)
          lst = lst.next
        tmp.append(lst.val)
        return tmp
        
      lst1 = linked_lst_to_lst(l1)
      lst2 = linked_lst_to_lst(l2)

      lst = sorted(lst1+lst2)
      print (lst)

        
      return create_linked_lst(lst)


l1 = create_linked_lst([1,2,4])
l2 = create_linked_lst([1,3,4])


#while l1.next != None:
#  print (l1.val)
#  l1 = l1.next
#print (l1.val)

test = Solution()
test.mergeTwoLists(l1,l2)
```

When uncommentting the while loop outside the class the output is

```
[1,1,2,3,4,4]
```

```
Your input
[1,2,4]
[1,3,4]
stdout
[1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4]

Output
[1,1,2,3,4,4,4]
Expected
[1,1,2,3,4,4]
```

when submitting to leetcode only the body of the `mergeTwoLists` method is copied along with the `create_linked_lst`

Answer (score 1):

The following line is problematic:

```py
if lst.index(item) < len(lst)-1:
```

There should be no reason to look for the index of the value. Moreover, this will not give the *current* index when there are duplicates in the list. Since your example result has a duplicate 4, also the final item will be added to the list in the loop, and *again* after the loop.

In fact, this logic is overly complex: it really is not needed to first create an empty node and then populate its value in a next iteration.

Here is a more elegant solution to convert a standard list to a linked list: iterate the input list in *reversed* order, and *prepend* that value to the linked list you are building. The constructor for `ListNode` allows to also pass the reference to the next node, and when you build the linked list in reverse, then that next node is really the *previous* state of the linked list.

This leads to this code:

```py
def create_linked_lst(lst):
    linked_lst = None
    for item in reversed(lst):
        linked_lst = ListNode(item, linked_lst)
    return linked_lst
```

Note also that there is no case where you create a node with `''` as value. Leet Code will expect you to return `None` when really the result linked list has no nodes.

#### Final remark

You solve the Leet Code challenge by turning linked list to standard lists. This will work, but the purpose of such challenges is to do it without O(n) auxiliary memory, and really do the job by manipulating the nodes of the linked lists.